# Is it possible to install dmg2img_1.6.1-1ubuntu2 on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, gnome-terminal

I wish to use an older version of dmg2img i.e. 1.6.1. However, the current version of dmg2img that I have is 1.6.2. Where is this file located?

Answer (score 0):

The binary can be found by using "which" command in linux:

`which dmg2img`

The location of all the files associated with a package can be found out by:

`dpkg -L dmg2img`

If you simply want to delete the current version, you can do so by:

`sudo apt-get remove dmg2img`

Then you can install the version that you wish to use manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in any of the Ubuntu mirrors, for example: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/dmg2img/

Install with:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/dmg2img/dmg2img_1.6.1-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i dmg2img_1.6.1-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

(change amd64 to i386 for 32-bit systems)